# Logic App Blob Trigger for a group of blobs

Tags: triggers, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I'm creating a Logic App that has to process all blobs that in a certain container. I would like to periodically check whether there are any new blobs and, if yes, start a run. I tried using the "When a blob is added or modified". However, if at the time of checking there are several new blobs, several new runs are initiated. Is there a way to only initiate one run if one or more blobs are added/modified?

I experimented with the "Number of blobs to return from the trigger" and also with the split-on setting, but I haven't found a way yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger with multiple blob files, yes you have to use `When a blob is added or modified`. From the [connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#when-a-blob-is-added-or-modified-(properties-only)) description you could know

> This operation triggers a flow when one or more blobs are added or modified in a container.

And you must set the `maxFileCount` also you already find the result is split into separate parts. This is because the default setting the [splitOn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#trigger-multiple-runs) is on, if you want the result be a whole you need to **set it OFF**.

[image]

[image]

The the result should be what you want.

[image]